# How to join 2 tables without a value error?

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have 2 dataframes:

```
        Country  electricity price
23     Pakistan              0.042
24  Afghanistan              0.042
25    Argentina              0.042
26    Sri Lanka              0.043
27        Egypt              0.043
```

and

```
         Country  Meal, Inexpensive Restaurant  Cappuccino (regular)
0    Afghanistan                          1.70                  1.08
1  Aland Islands                         12.15                  3.53
2        Albania                          4.31                  1.10
3       Alderney                         21.61                  3.41
4        Algeria                          2.13                  0.57
```

*Afghanistan is the common row*

I wanted to join them so I used
`a1.join(b1,on='Country')`. However, it keeps showing the value error:

`ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`

I have checked the type of data in country it is string, and there is no null values that might have confused it.. any idea what could be the cause to such an issue ?

Comment: Seems like you simply want: `df1.merge(df2, on='Country')`. Will get you a `df` with only Afghanistan in `Country` and its associated values for the other 3 cols.

Comment: `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Country')`?